# Android 7.0 nougat unable to change system date

Tags: android, date

Android 7.0 nougat  i am unable to change system date if i set to from now to 2 or 3 month later and say ok then again if i open change date popup from setting it display current date. I also turned off automatic date turn off.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is about using android, and not e.g. programming android? If so, then you'd be ontopic at http://android.stackexchange.com/ instead of here.

Comment: Unsolved issue with a work-around available only for few. See: [How to change date and time format on Marshmallow?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/135743/16575) and [Customize date display format on Android 7](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/186774/16575)